# Find $\lim_{p\to \infty}p.\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim_{p\to \infty}p.\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)$

---

Let $L$= $\lim_{p\to \infty}p.\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)$
$=\lim_{p\to \infty}\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)^p$
But i am stuck here.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right) =1+(1-p)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1p\right)$$

Now $\ln\left(1+\dfrac1p\right)=\dfrac1p-\dfrac1{2p^2}+\dfrac1{3p^3}-\cdots$